# use of deleted function - std::atomic

Tags: c++, gcc

This is the declaration I have in .h file:

```
static std::atomic<int> OrdersExecutorIdCounter;
```

This is initilization from .cpp file:

```
std::atomic<int> ActionBasedOrdersExecutor::OrdersExecutorIdCounter = 0;
```

It compiles just fine in VC++, but in gcc 4.8 I get this error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show the exact compilation command.

Comment: Think about what this code does in theory. Hint: copy-initialization makes a difference.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++0x -I"/home/oleg/eclipseWorkspace/CommonsLibrary" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"ActionBasedOrdersExecutor.d" -MT"ActionBasedOrdersExecutor.d" -o "ActionBasedOrdersExecutor.o" "../ActionBasedOrdersExecutor.cpp"`, i've removed some `-I` as not important

Comment: @javapowered - Possible (similar) duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27314485/1971003

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can directly initialise the atomic variable, which does not require **deleted** copy constructor, eg:

```
std::atomic<int> ActionBasedOrdersExecutor::OrdersExecutorIdCounter{0};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need (or want) to initialize your atomic integer to 0 (the int value would be 0 initialized for a global).