# "Use of deleted function" error with std::atomic_int

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

I want to use an `std::atomic_int` variable. In my code, I have:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_int stop = 0;

int main()
{
    // Do something
}
```

And this gives me a compile error:

```
use of deleted function 'std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::__atomic_base(const std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>&) [with _ITp = int]'
 std::atomic_int stop = 0;
                        ^
```

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: Surely boost/thread.hpp is irrelevant here? Does the problem persist when you remove the header?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with boost really...not sure why I included that! The problem remains even after removing the header.

Comment: [Repro in GCC 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/990a12fc81ea21de)

Comment: Apparently the compiler thinks you are doing `std::atomic_int stop = std::atomic_int(0);`, and that will not work as the copy-constructor is deleted. Instead try to do direct initialization, like `std::atomic_int stop{0};`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think a thorough reading of the specification might be needed to understand if this is the intended behavior.

Comment: copy-initialization requires an accessible copy-constructor

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Bah yes I always forget about this rule. Standardese now available below.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your code is attempting to construct a temporary `std::atomic_int` on the RHS, then use the `std::atomic_int` copy constructor (which is `delete`d) to initialise `stop`, like so:

```
std::atomic_int stop = std::atomic_int(0);
```

That's because *copy-initialisation*, as you are performing here, is not quite equivalent to other kinds of initialisation.

> `[C++11: 8.5/16]:` The semantics of initializers are as follows *[..]*
>
> **If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is *list-initialized*** (8.5.4).

(this allows for option 3, at the end of this answer)

> *[..]*
>
> **If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:**
>
> - If the initialization is *direct-initialization*, or **if it is *copy-initialization* where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered.** The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

(this almost describes your code but not quite; the key here is that, perhaps contrary to intuition, `std::atomic_int`'s constructors are not considered at all in your case!)

> - **Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining *copy-initialization* cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.** The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type. The temporary is a prvalue. **The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to *direct-initialize*, according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the *copy-initialization*.** In certain cases, an implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this *direct-initialization* by constructing the intermediate result directly into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

(this is your scenario; so, although the copy can be elided, it still must be possible)

> - *[..]*

---

Here's the fix, anyway; use *direct-initialisation* or *list-initialisation*:

```
std::atomic_int stop(0);     // option 1
std::atomic_int stop{0};     // option 2
std::atomic_int stop = {0};  // option 3
```

Comment: Yes, this works thanks. So it seems that a default constructor without any arguments does not exist, and you need to provide an explicit value as you have it. Thanks!

Comment: @Karnivaurus: It has nothing to do with any default constructor. You're providing arguments.

Comment: Isn't that the case for mostly any type? `T a = x;` creates a temporary `T` constructed from `x`, and then initialises `a` from that temporary. Copy elision may eliminate the temporary, but the copy constructor must nonetheless be available.

Comment: Ah, yes, I found the wording. Standardese incoming!

Comment: And option 3: `std::atomic_int stop = {0};`. This is copy-initialization, but copy-initialization using a braced-init-list performs copy-list-initialization, which does not involve temporaries (in this case).

Comment: @hvd: Option and its standardese (well, some of it) added

Comment: Option 1 is not list-initialisation ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Very nice answer, +1 !!

Comment: C++17 makes the code in the question compile.  https://godbolt.org/z/uNswJL.  But even `-std=gnu++14` doesn't make it legal, so it was something new in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

> ```cpp
> std::atomic_int stop = 0;
> ```

... is *copy-initialization*. This means that you're not directly initializing the `stop` to a value of zero, but rather, you're creating a temporary object and then calling the copy constructor of `std::atomic_int`, as if by:

```cpp
std::atomic_int temporary(0); // this would be okay
std::atomic_int stop = temporary; // this isn't (use of deleted copy constructor)
```

In C++11, the compiler is allowed to optimize this to not call the copy constructor, but only if the type is copyable or movable. `std::atomic` isn't. If it isn't, then this code is ill-formed.

#### C++17

Note that your code is perfectly valid in C++17. This is due to *mandatory copy elision*. It is guaranteed that

```cpp
std::atomic_int stop = 0;
```

... doesn't call the copy or move constructor at all, so it is valid.

On a side note, the prior restrictions can be annoying in projects that prefer the use of `auto`:

```cpp
auto m = std::mutex{}; // invalid in C++14, valid in C++17
```

#### See Also

- [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/5740428)
- [How does guaranteed copy elision work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/5740428)

Answer (score -4):

In my case I had de following errors (Examples):

• ‘std::literals’ has not been declared

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
```

• “Use of deleted function” error with std::random_device{}

```
std::random_device device = std::random_device{}
```

Check what is your selected C++ Standard. In my case on debug mode I had selected -std=c++17, ALL OK. But on Release mode I had selected -std:c++11, tons of errors.

**Update**
Tested on Clion Windows 2018.3 with remote Linux compile.

Using -std=c++11
[image: Using -std=c++11]

Using -std=c++17
[image: Using -std=c++17]

C ++ is an evolving standard: after 2003 there were 2011 (C ++ 11), then 2014 (C ++ 14) and now we have 2017 (C ++ 17) and we are working for 2020 (C ++ 20) . Many things are changing, they are deprecated, other features are new. If you want the latest update, you should use the most recent standard, if your software has code that may be deprecated then you have to use the standard with which it was created.

Comment: Okay, let's try this another way then. In what way does this answer address the question about initialising `std::atomic_int`?

Comment: Your answer has merit in that you're saying the posted code works as expected in a newer standard (C++17) and is a good addition given that this is an old question. However, I agree that there is a lot of noise not relevant to the original question (string_literals, random_device, clion, cmake)

Comment: It is true that there is a lot of noise, but nobody has started in C ++ programming knowing everything. There are people who start from 0 without having an idea of all the problems and features of C ++.

Comment: I've been learning this beautiful language for 6 months and I think I have a long way to go. But it is something so sad that people write this "This does not appear to be relevant to anything on this page", only to demean what another person writes by saying that simple sentence. Noise is for people who know less and need the complete instruction manual.

Comment: The comment "This does not appear relevant" is not meant to demean, it is meant to encourage you to improve your answer by *making* it more relevant, in this case either by clarifying or simplifying it. An answer to a question like this isn't supposed to be a "complete instruction manual"; answers are more useful if they are clear and to the point. If people need help with C++17, there are other answers on this site that address problems more directly and comprehensively.

Comment: This doesn't explain what changed in C++17 that makes it legal to init an atomic variable with `= 0`.  The answer reads like you're saying you had similar "use of deleted function" errors from `std::random_device{} `.  Nowhere (except in those small hard-to-read pictures of your whole dev-env) does this answer actually say that C++17 makes the code in the question compile.  (That is the case, though.  https://godbolt.org/z/uNswJL.  Even `-std=gnu++14` doesn't make it legal, so it was something new in C++17.)