# error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<unsigned int>&)’

Tags: c++, c++14, stdatomic

While trying to compile the code base of a [project from a Git repository](https://github.com/utcs-scea/DGSF-AvA), I came across the following error:

```bash
DGSF-AvA/worker/serverless_gpu/svgpu_manager.cpp:90:78: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<unsigned int>&)’
             printf("not my turn:  me %u  turn %u\n", current_id, current_turn);
                                                                              ^
```

I searched for the reason behind the issue and found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27314485/7571421).

Based on the question above and the solution stated, I assume the error to be caused by the line given below (in the [file](https://github.com/utcs-scea/DGSF-AvA/blob/d986b63b1a9356830a25b934dbe95bb59c7e4b86/worker/serverless_gpu/svgpu_manager.cpp#L67-L93)):

```cpp
...
...
std::atomic<uint32_t> current_turn(0); //<------Suspected line causing the issue
uint32_t current_id(0);
std::mutex sched_lock;

ava_proto::WorkerAssignReply SVGPUManager::HandleRequest(const ava_proto::WorkerAssignRequest &request) {
    ava_proto::WorkerAssignReply reply;

    if (request.gpu_count() > 1) {
        std::cerr << "ERR: someone requested more than 1 GPU, no bueno" << std::endl;
        return reply;
    }

    sched_lock.lock();
    uint32_t q_id = current_id;
    current_id += 1;
    sched_lock.unlock();

    uint32_t gpu_mem = request.gpu_mem()[0];

    //std::cerr << "[SVLESS-MNGR]: API server request arrived, asking for schedule with memory " << gpu_mem << std::endl;
    while (true) {
        //if not our turn, wait
        if (current_turn != current_id) {
            printf("not my turn:  me %u  turn %u\n", current_id, current_turn); // <--- line which complains of the deleted function
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        }
...
...
```

I assumed the reason to be similar to what was mentioned in the linked question thread. But, the way `current_turn` is initialized here is suggested as a valid solution in the answer to the linked question.

I even tried out the few other options listed in the solution:

```cpp
std::atomic<uint32_t> current_turn{0};
```

```cpp
std::atomic<uint32_t> current_turn = {0};
```

But none of the above alternatives gets rid of the issue. I find that the data type of `current_turn` is `std::atomic<uint32_t>` (different from the data type `std::atomic_int` mentioned in the question)

Also, the project I am talking about uses `CMake`. The compiler standard is declared as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

So, the project is built using `C++14` instead of `C++11`(in the question linked). Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Please guide me on why this question does not meet the StackOverflow guideline. Then, I can modify the question accordingly.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic "std::atomic is neither copyable nor movable." Use `printf("not my turn:  me %u  turn %u\n", current_id, current_turn.load());` instead, or you could use `std::cout` since you're using C++.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Because it's a duplicate of an already-answered question about printing the value of a `std::atomic` integer which searching for `printf std::atomic` should have found.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. I understand that I should have searched a bit more. But it did not click to me during that time that `printf` might be the cause, like did not see it from the angle of `printf` being the culprit. (Actually, I am not the author of the codebase, it is written by someone else) and I assumed them to have a running code when they wrote it. (So, that they wrote `printf` to print some atomic stuff, I implicitly assumed that they might have tested it. That assumption wasn't good on my part.) I assumed something might have changed in the C++ standard. I was more worried on that

Comment: I wonder if it compiles with any existing compilers?  Turns out yes, MSVC is just broken and doesn't reject this code: https://godbolt.org/z/jxb6x8efP .  I thought it might be assuming implicit conversion to to `unsigned`  since the copy-constructor isn't an option.  But no, the warning message says `<source>(6): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%u' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'std::atomic<unsigned int>'`, implying that it *is* passing a copy of the std::atomic object!

Comment: Confirmed with non-lock-free `atomic<big_struct>` which has sizeof=36 vs. the underlying `big_struct` having size 32 (MSVC includes the mutex in the object); we can see MSVC actually copy the whole thing to the stack as an arg for printf 2x movups plus a 32-bit `mov`, confirming that it didn't actually treat it as an implicit `.load()` despite the warning message.  https://godbolt.org/z/WrGa3KaGb .  Anyway, this codebase was probably only tested with MSVC.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks a lot for giving this insight, like how MSVC is a bit faulty and passes the copy of the object to the stack. Yes, I think that might be the case that the code base was only tested with MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::atomic` is not a primitive type and can't be used in `printf`, and it can't be copied. You might want to use `current_turn.load()` in `printf`.